# Reading data object in one transaction after comitting data object in another transaction - dirty read?

Tags: database, commit, dirtyread

By definition, a dirty read is a read of uncommitted data. My question is:

If you have several writes from different transactions in the same story happening right after each other (lets say transaction 1, 2 and 3), then at the end of the writes, one of the transactions commits (lets say it was transaction 1), followed by a read from transaction 2 or 3, does this count as a dirty read?

Ex: w1(X);w2(X);w3(X);c1;r2(X).....

Answer (score 0):

No, the term for these is nonrepeatable reads or phantom reads ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)). They are allowed by default in many (if not most) database engines.